# Single value capacitor or two different in parallel for filtering the power supply for microcontroller

Tags: capacitor, resonance, ceramic, best-practice

I am trying to design power supply for the STM32F446 for my PCB.

I wonder if I should stick to the [Datasheet of STM32F446 Page 71](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/65/cb/75/50/53/d6/48/24/DM00141306.pdf/files/DM00141306.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00141306.pdf)  and use two capacitors or be careful about it and maybe just use one 100nF. The picture from Datasheet with suggested values:

[image]

I started getting these concerns after checking some other designs, where they just used one 100nF capacitor for this micro-controller. As-well after reading this answer on [StackExchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/327980/221561) about the effect of 'anti-resonance' when using two different values capacitors. He also referenced to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/320363/antiresonance-of-multiple-parallel-decoupling-capacitors-use-same-value-or-mult) where it was elaborated in more details. In [these slides](http://ntuemc.tw/upload/file/20120419205619a4fcf.pdf) they mention that 'anti-resonance' effect can be reduced by reducing ESL.

I am a bit confused by all these inputs. I think the most trusted source is definitely manufacturer Datasheet, but maybe they assume I would be using some special capacitors (for example ceramic X7R), or something else I am not taking into account. And why other designs don't follow this suggestion. It would be great if you can clarify this.

Comment: Ceramic X7R aren’t special, especially 100nF.  However, the datasheet will show best practice, but you may well get away with much less, although if something goes horribly wrong you won’t have the defence that you followed the datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

Manufacturer suggestions should just work.

They even mention that removing filtering capacitors might cause incorrect operation of the device.

You should do as the manufacturer says, and then worry if it does not work properly.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I was also looking for reasoning behind this approach. Why in this case manufacturer, when giving suggestion, is not concerned with anti-resonance effect?

Answer (score 0):

The idea in the datasheet is that you have a smaller local bypass capacitor and a larger bulk capacitor located further away (possibly near the power connection).  The longer distance will contribute resistance which will damp the antiresonance peaks at least somewhat.  In many cases, larger bulk capacitors will be electrolytic, which are even more resistant, although that is not the case here.

In this specific case, since the bulk capacitance value they recommend is tiny and could easily fit into a 0603 or even 0402 package, you could consider simply bypassing with a 1uF cap (or even larger to account for decrease in capacitance at bias if your package size has a significant degree of that).  Using only one capacitor will prevent any antiresonance peaks.  Since you will not need to use a large package to obtain the recommended bulk capacitance, you will not increase inductance (at least to any meaningful degree) by using a larger value for bypassing.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. Yeah, I agree that the package size plays really important role here as-well. Was just curious why they suggest then using 2 in parallel? So they want me to place them a bit far away?

Comment: @Vaso  In the past you could not get large value 0402 MLCCs, so using a single capacitor for bulk and decoupling was not possible, or at least much more expensive.  In recent years MLCCs have gotten a lot better. The recommendation may simply be old.  Another possibility is cost optimization, where multiple chips could share the 1uF while the MCU uses a cheaper 0.1uF for decoupling.

Answer (score 0):

100 nF in parallel to 1 uF is a recommendation that holds since the 70's.

They are a low-ESR close-proximity energy source for the VDD of your microcontroller.

Without those capacitors, current will be drawn from the closest capacitor or directly from the on-board LDO or DC-DC converter which, in turn, will draw current from the external power supply.

The worst scenario, in terms of EMC compliance, is when the current is drawn from the on-board LDO or DC-DC converter because the PCB tracks are long and act as antennas.

PCB tracks are not efficient antennas but still they irradiate RF energy when fast varying currents flow into them.

Currents drawn by micro controllers contains a lot of frequencies because CMOS circuits switch fast.

It's very important that microcontrollers currents are drawn from local and close-proximity capacitors.

X7R ceramic capacitors are the best choice because the ceramic characteristics are stable over a wide range of temperature.

Every single VDD pin of your microcontroller needs at least the 100 nF ceramic capacitor.

If cost, as always, is important then share the capacitor of 1uF value.

---

Resonances

Capacitors have parasitic components inside and it's not that easy to estimate the impact that they have on the EMC signature of your board.

What people do when they have to go in an EMC lab is bringing with them a certain number of SMD ceramic capacitors and a solder iron.

If EMC problems arise, they change a couple of capacitors on the board and repeat the test.

---

By my experience I can tell you that 470 uF to 1500 uF low ESR electrolytic capacitor as an input filter of the LDO or DC-DC converter of the board solve 90% of the problems.

I love United Chemicon electrolytic capacitors because the are really low ESR capacitors and because I was able to pass the EMC compliance tests if one of my boards thanks to them.

Comment: No, every single VDD pin does not require the two capacitors. That picture only shows two supply rails, there are a lot more VDD pins for digital supply, up to 12 that are not visible. Every supply node as a whole needs one large capacitor, and each supply pin needs a single 100nF. Just like the datasheet says.

Comment: I said that: share the largest capacitors.

Comment: You did, but before that you said as a fact that the chip needs two capacitors on every single VDD pin, and then you said they can be left out so it is unclear if they are needed or not needed. So I just wished to mention for confused readers that the claim they both are needed for each pin is neither true nor in line with datasheet suggestions.

Comment: Hey, regarding the shared 1uF. Only for these 2 pins they suggest using 2 in parallel - 1uF and 100nF since _VDDA_ is used for ADC power, and it needs extra stability. For other VDD pins however, they suggest  to share one at least 4.7uF. Question arises how to place shared one compared to the IC, if I have power plane, and just use vias to connect the capacitor to power (I mean, if I want to have only one shared, I can place it on the power of only one pin - it means it will not be that useful for other VDDs- and there are 6 of them)

Comment: Along with 6-layer boards with stiching vias around the border, I always put a capacitor of 1500 uF, by United Chemicon, on my VDD line because I don't trust FAE's. I've tested in quite a few boards since 2001 in EMC testing labs and I realized that below 1000 uF I had problems.